# Grails file upload - how to recognize file and/or content type?

Tags: grails, file-upload, content-type, file-type

I'm a Grails beginner, so please be patient with me. Currently I'm having hard times manipulating file uploads. As far as I understand using `request.getFile()` I can easily get the stream of bytes. But before I do that, I want to check the following:

- file name of the file being uploaded
- file size of the file being uploaded
- content/file type of the file being uploaded

How can this be done? Is it even possible before the file is uploaded to the server? I would like to block uploading of large files.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on the front end or back end?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the information is contained in the [`CommonsMultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) object that you can cast your request parameter to.

You can use it like that (in your controller)

```
def uploaded = {
    def CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile = params.fileInputName
    def contentType = uploadedFile.contentType 
    def fileName = uploadedFile.originalFilename
    def size = uploadedFile.size
}
```

As far as blocking large file uploads, this could be done by adding the following to your form:

```
<INPUT name="fileInputName" type="file" maxlength="100000">
```

but not all browsers will support it. The other limit is you container upload limit (see Tomcat configuration or whatever container you are using).

Other than that, you have to check the size and reject it in the controller.

Comment: All this provided you are using a simple HTML form submission.

Comment: Great and helpful answer. You just saved me a lot of time. Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Or you can get uploaded file properties directly without using `CommonsMultipartFile`.

```
def ufile = request.getFile("fileInputName")
println(ufile.contentType)
println(ufile.originalFilename)
println(ufile.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

From server side it is possible to use the configuration at `application.yml` to limit file size application wide.

Just insert this code on your `application.yml`:

```
grails:
  controllers:
    upload:
      maxFileSize: 3145728 # 3 * 1024 * 1024 = 3 MB The maximum file size
      maxRequestSize: 3145728 # The maximum request size
```

See:

[Grails Guide - upload file](http://guides.grails.org/grails-upload-file/guide/index.html)

[Grails3 file upload maxFileSize limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532126/3776661)