# Grails3 file upload maxFileSize limit

Tags: grails, spring-boot, grails-3.0

I am trying to update the file upload maxFileSize limit in Grails 3 and tried the configuration in `src/main/resources/application.properties`, `application.groovy` and `application.yml`, but it's still throwing the exception

```
Class
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException
Message
    the request was rejected because its size (154738) exceeds the configured maximum (128000)
```

Any help on where and what to configure in a Grails 3 application?

Comment: Setting the limits is easy in application.yml though the difficult part is to handle the exception when the max file size is violated, none of the solutions provided seems to work, though here there is a solution https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-mvc-how-to-handle-max-upload-size-exceeded-exception/

Answer (score 54):

**Grails 3, Grails 4, Grails 5 and Grails 6**

The solution is to set `maxFileSize` and `maxRequestSize` limits inside your `application.yml` file (usually placed inside `grails-app/conf/`). Be sure to have something like this:

```
grails:
    controllers:
        upload:
            maxFileSize: 2000000
            maxRequestSize: 2000000
```

Replace `2000000` with the **number of max bytes** you want for a file upload and for the entire request. [Grails 3](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3.0.x/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L73), [Grails 4](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.3/guide/theWebLayer.html#_increase_upload_max_file_size), [Grails 5](https://docs.grails.org/5.1.4/guide/single.html#_increase_upload_max_file_size) and [Grails 6 default](https://docs.grails.org/6.0.0-M1/guide/single.html#_increase_upload_max_file_size) is 128000 (~128KB).

---

---

#### FAQ

**1. How to convert from MB to bytes?**

```
YOUR_MAX_SIZE_IN_MB * 1024 * 1024 = BYTES
```

E.g. *Convert 5 MB in bytes*

```
5 * 1024 * 1024 = **5242880** bytes
```

**2. Security**

As [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) says

> Limit the file size to a maximum value in order to prevent denial of service attacks

So these limits exist to prevent DoS attacks and to enforce overall application performance (bigger request size == more memory used from the server).

**3. What is the right value for `maxFileSize` and `maxRequestSize`?**

It depends on the application type, but it's generally a bad idea to keep them too high. If you really need to upload big files, probably you should develop (or use) a dedicated (and separated) service.

Comment: How does this work with grails 4? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892143/multipart-file-upload-maxfilesize-exceeded

Comment: the key of the question is how to handle the SizeLimitExceededException exception, since any value that could be set could also be violated

Comment: no @PabloPazos, the OP asked clearly about how to configure the size limit. You are talking about another topic - exception handling.

Comment: The exception will still happen after the configuration is done, just upload a bigger file, so that is still part of the problem

Answer (score 7):

Part of the problem is setting a max file size. The other problem is handling that error gracefully.

Here is my bean definition:

```
multipartResolver(MyMultipartResolver) {
    maxUploadSize = (5*1024*1024)
}
```

Here is my implementation:

```
public class MyMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

    static final String FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR = "fileSizeExceeded";

    public MultipartHttpServletRequest resolveMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return super.resolveMultipart(request);
        } catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
            request.setAttribute(FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR, true);
            return new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile>(), new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>(), new LinkedHashMap<String, String>());
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being to check for the request attribute in your controller or a filter to determine if the file was too large.

Comment: When I did this, files within limits were lost. Do you know whats wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I also had no luck trying to set new maximum values in application.properties or application.yml.

What does work though is using a bean definition in conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
   multipartResolver(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver){
        maxInMemorySize=1000000
        maxUploadSize=100000000
        //uploadTempDir="/tmp"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this which needed commons file-upload library on classpath 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.1'. It still fails with same exception. Is there any additional settings?

Comment: I didn't need additional settings, and I also don't need a dependency on commons-fileupload. Something else must be going on in your application.

Comment: I added this:     `compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'`   BTW, only this seemed to work.  It ignored the other settings (Grails 3.2.11).

Comment: I used this answer in combination with dependencies comment. Solved the error but now the file in the request is null.

Comment: I also get a null file in the request on Grails 3.3.10

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/668

```
grails.controllers.upload.maxFileSize
```

and/or

```
grails.controllers.upload.maxRequestSize
```

config properties/settings

Answer (score 3):

Try this
https://github.com/zyro23/grails-core-668/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.yml

upload:
            maxFileSize: 9999999999
            maxRequestSize: 9999999999

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33532126/3340702) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me(grails 3.3.9):
in `conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver()
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(2000000)
}
```

in `MyFile.groovy` domain

```
package attainrvtwo

class MyFile {

    byte[] myFile

    static constraints = {
        myFile(maxSize: 2000000)
    }
}
```

at the end of `conf/application.yml`

```
---
grails:
  controllers:
    upload:
      maxFileSize: 2000000
      maxRequestSize: 2000000
```

Comment: How do you handle the exception when the file is bigger than the max?