# How to catch "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException" in Grails 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, grails, grails-3.0

I'm having an awfully hard time catching the error: `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException`

I have the following code:

```
final class UploadTextCommand  {
   MultipartFile contents
   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

Additionally to handle the post of the file I have this action:

```
def upload = { UploadTextCommand -> 
   ...code...
}
```

I've got these settings in the "application.yml" file to force the error:

```
controllers:
    upload:
        maxFileSize: 100
        maxRequestSize: 100
```

So I can reliably recreate the exception, but I can't catch it before the browser shows a horrible view:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException
```

Please tell me how to catch this error in Grails. Just using a try/catch in the upload action fails miserably.

Added stack trace on request of commenter:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (318635) exceeds the configured maximum (100000)
grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.logThrowable(AbstractFilter.java:116)
grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:70)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:73)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:188)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:171)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
```

Comment: Could you show verbose stacktrace of this error?

Comment: @MichalSzulc I've added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You can find in a stacktrace:

> the request was rejected because its size (318635) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (100000)

and in your code:

```
controllers:
    upload:
        maxFileSize: 100
        maxRequestSize: 100
```

you should exceed `maxFileSize`, but if you want to handle exception [check this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974072/2166188). IMHO cleaner solution would be implementation of your own `before filter` or `interceptor`.