# How to handle FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException on Grails 3?

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails3

I have an app that allows users to upload files, I can't control the size of the files they are uploading, and maxFileSize will always be finite.

If the user uploads a file that is bigger than maxFileSize, there is an internal exception I need to grab to present the error to the user, but the exception seems to be thrown from the Servlet.service() before reaching the contoller (even the exception is a Tomcat thing).

How can I catch that exception in a controller to be able to show the user an error using Grails 3?

FYI, this is the trace I get:

```
2020-06-26 14:35:28.158 ERROR --- [nio-8095-exec-7] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : SizeLimitExceededException occurred when processing request: [POST] /operationalTemplate/upload
the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880). Stacktrace follows:

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(GrailsDispatcherServlet.groovy:75)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.getHttpMethodOverride(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:60)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)
        ... 5 common frames omitted

2020-06-26 14:35:28.171 ERROR --- [nio-8095-exec-7] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)] with root cause

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6530988) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.getHttpMethodOverride(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098826/how-to-cach-org-springframework-web-multipart-multipartexception-in-grails-3 ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't show how to handle the exception. On an answer there is a code I found online that was for grails 1.x and didn't work for grails 3.