# HandlerExceptionResolver, MaxUploadSizeExceededException - Upload continues and error not returned immediately

Tags: spring, spring-security, handlerexceptionresolver

I am using Spring 3.1.1. I have a file upload feature and have implemented HandlerExceptionResolver to handle file size limit. I have configured the size in spring mvc xml with "maxUploadSize" attribute. My application uses spring security with open id.

I am using the code below in resolveException() of that upload controller. RestResponse is a pojo with error message and status

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setView(new MappingJacksonJsonView());
RestResponse fail_response = new RestResponse();
fail_response.setMessage("Max upload limit failure.");
fail_response.setStatus("FAIL");
mav.addObject("restResponse", fail_response);
return mav;
```

I can see from the logs that, the resolveException() is invoked, however the json response is not shown in the rest api client/browser. I can see the exception in the log (Maximum upload size of 10485760 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (30611515) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)) immediately after the upload, but the upload still continues and after a while the json error message (available above) is shown in the browser.

I did check for this problem in stackoverflow and other portals and could not find why it is not shown or response is returned to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/668) and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845943/grails3-file-upload-maxfilesize-limit). If still not clear, refer to [this link](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-core-668/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.yml)

and search for maxFileSize and maxRequestSize. Add same settings in your application.yml