# Grails 3 (3.1.10) MultipartResolver

Tags: grails, file-upload, config, multipart

My Grails application uses [`StandardServletMultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html), by default, instead of [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.10/ref/Plug-ins/controllers.html).

How can I configure my app to use the `CommonsMultipartResolver`? Or otherwise, how can I configure `maxFileSize` for `StandardServletMultipartResolver`?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532126/3340702) could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

See the following settings: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/339a8d84594430150d0a5587a93b6565fa0357e5/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/config/Settings.groovy#L110

More specifically `grails.controllers.upload.maxFileSize`