# Grails params in controller empty on too large post request

Tags: groovy, grails

I send a post request with large body to grails server.

Tested locally and with production.
For send using python requests.

like this `requests.post(UPLOAD_URL, data = data, headers = HEADERS)`

if `data` contains `~2mb` - I see empty params in grails debugger in controller
I'm not trying to upload a file, just a payload (but big size).

Is there any config in grails that could block my attempts?

Small data works fine.

**UPDATED** Just a `python-requests` issue. `NodeJS` upload works fine with 6.5 mb
`grails.controllers.upload.requestMaxSize` configured well

Still solving

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845943/grails3-file-upload-maxfilesize-limit/33532126#33532126

Comment: It seems like a python issue