# How to get the file extension in grails?

Tags: grails

> I recently started working on grails and i want to know how to get the
>        extension of a file. Ex: test.txt. I want to check extension(txt)?
>        any clue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019478/grails-file-upload-how-to-recognize-file-and-or-content-type

Comment: Please dont mind. What exactly the contentType will return ? is it same as mediaType. Like mediaType will return text/plain for .txt file and the same will return for xml json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way. Using a regular expression.

```
def fileName = 'something.ext'
def matcher = (fileName =~ /.*\.(.*)$/)

if(matcher.matches()) {
    def extension = matcher[0][1]

    if(extension in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']) {
        // Good to go
        println 'ok'
    } else {
        println 'not ok'
    }
} else {
    println 'No file extension found'
}
```

Comment: will this regEx work for .doc .docx .pdf .xlsx .xls .txt ??

Comment: Yes. The regex boils down to: everything after the last period. So it can handle file extensions of arbitrary length. Just add them to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to get the file extension.

With groovy, the following operation will give you the file extension of any file name:

```
def fileName = ...
def fileExt = fileName - ~/.*(?<=\.)/
```

The accepted answer goes a bit further and tries to check for specific file extensions. You can use the match operator `==~` to do this as well:

```
assert fileName ==~ ~/.*(?<=\.)(txt|jpe?g|png)/
```

This assertion will work provided the file name ends with one of the supplied extensions.

---

<sup>Also noticed that groovy can do positive lookbehind using `(<?\.)`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> Hope i found the answer of my Question. How to find the extension
>       of a file.

```js
String fileName = "something.ext";
        int a = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        String extName = fileName.substring(a);
        System.out.println(fileName.substring(a));
        ArrayList<String> extList = new ArrayList<String>();
        extList.add("jpg");
        extList.add("jpeg");
        extList.add("png");
        if(extList.contains(extName))
        {
            System.out.println("proceed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("throw exception");
        }
```

[Lsat comment at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326610/how-to-add-validation-for-file-type-in-grails)